# Android, associate file extension with app

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application, which should be able to open files with extension ".inv", both from file system and from email attachment.
After spending a lot of time I finally made it work and I share my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <!-- Handling the files with mimeType="application/inv"
            and any file extension -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/inv"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Handling the files with any mimeType
            and file extension ".inv" -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.inv"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
```